# Python: Print in rows

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
food_list = ['apple', 'pear', 'tomato', 'bean', 'carrot', 'grape']
```

How would I print the list in rows containing 4 columns, so it would look like:

```
apple pear tomato bean   
carrot grape
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
food_list = ['apple', 'pear', 'tomato', 'bean', 'carrot', 'grape']
for i in xrange(0, len(food_list), 4):
    print '\t'.join(food_list[i:i+4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
food_list = ['apple', 'pear', 'tomato', 'bean', 'carrot', 'grape']
size = 4
g = (food_list[i:i+size] for i in xrange(0, len(food_list), size))
for i in g:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
food_list = ['apple', 'pear', 'tomato', 'bean', 'carrot', 'grape']
index = 0
for each_food in food_list:
    if index < 3:
            print each_food,
            index += 1
    else:
            print each_food
            index = 0
```