# Python and HTML table

Tags: python, html

I'm using the code below to print out rows containing 4 columns. How would I append each value in the list to a HTML table that also contains rows with four columns?

```
   random_list = ['car', 'plane', 'van', 'boat', 'ship', 'jet','shuttle']
    for i in xrange(0, len(food_list), 4):
        print '\t'.join(food_list[i:i+4])
```

Comment: Strange that this question was asked by a different user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214926/python-print-in-rows

Comment: Yup were on the same team trying to get this website up and running

Comment: The code posted won't work, since the list created is 'random_list', but the list parsed is 'food_list'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some minor modification...

```
food_list = ['car', 'plane', 'van', 'boat', 'ship', 'jet','shuttle']
for i in xrange(0, len(food_list), 4):
    print '<tr><td>' + '</td><td>'.join(food_list[i:i+4]) + '</td></tr>'
```

This basically changes the delimiter to not be tab, but the table elements. Also, puts the open row and close row at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on orangeoctopus' answer, using another [join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), rather than concatenation:

```
random_list = ['car', 'plane', 'van', 'boat', 'ship', 'jet','shuttle']
print "<table>"
for i in xrange(0, len(random_list), 4):
    print ''.join(['<tr><td>','</td><td>'.join(random_list[i:i+4]),'</td></tr>'])
print '</table>'
```

Comment: What are the benefits of using join over concatenation? Seems rather silly (no offense, I'm genuinely curious).

Comment: @orangeoctopus:  When gluing together strings, it seems join() is considered more pythonic than concatenation.  Also, when the number of items being glued gets large, join() runs faster.  However, for a small number of items, I think concatenation is fine and is what I usually do (habit from other languages).