# How to print the elements of a list in rows?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

this is my 1st question here.
I have a dictionary of this format

```
hostLoc = {'Continent1': list of hosts, 'Continent2': list of hosts ...}
```

where host is an instance of a class

e.g.

```
hostLoc = {'Europe': [Active Pr1Host10: 1.0/1.0 , 1.0/1.0 , 10 , E , 2 , Europe , 1], 'Australia': [Active Pr1Host02: 1.0/1.0 , 1.0/1.0 , 10 , E , 1 , Australia , 1, Active Pr1Host05: 1.0/1.0 , 1.0/1.0 , 10 , E , 1 , Australia , 1, Active Pr1Host13: 1.0/1.0 , 1.0/1.0 , 10 , E , 3 , Australia , 1].....}
```

I would like to print something like

```
Continent1
host1 -TAB- host2
host3 -TAB- host4
Continent2
host1 -TAB- host2
host3
...
```

I modified [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215035/2960286) solution like this

```
print 'Host Details'
for location in hostLoc.keys():
    print '\n', location
    index = 0
    for host in hostLoc[location]:
        if index < 1:
                print host, '\t',
                index += 1
        else:
                print host
                index = 0
```

My problem is that in the output some tabs are "ignored" and some continents are separated by two lines instead of one.

Comment: is hostLoc() a function, or why are you using `()`. If it is a function, you should cache the result, and not re-call it every time

Comment: oops sorry. it is not a function (mistake copy - paste)...
I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're talking about, there's a far easier way to do it, namely to use the join function. '`\t'.join(array)` will separate all elements in array with a `\t`. You could try something like this:

```
for location in hostLoc:    #This gets all of the keys, and is more pythonic than hostLoc.keys()
    print '\t'.join(hostLoc[location])+'\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I forgot to mention that the hosts are classes. When I try your solution I get the error
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, Host found

Comment: @user2960286, your `Host` instance holds its value somewhere? Like `Host.host`. So then you have to do: `print '\t'.join([host.host for host in hostLoc[location]]) + '\n'`

Comment: I have the __repr__ method that returns e.g for host Pr1Host10:
Active Pr1Host10: 1.0/1.0 , 1.0/1.0 , 10 , E , 2 , Europe , 1
If I execute the code
print '\t'.join([host.__repr__() for host in hostLoc[location]]) + '\n'
I get all the hosts in one line and in some cases without tabs.
What I want is 2 or 3 hosts per line.